# one more Raid 1 conflagration on Centos

Tags: centos, raid

i have Centos server ,and there is already RAID 1 configured with two Hard drive each of them is 1TB ,i want to add two more Hard drive each of them is also 1TB and configure with RAID 1 ,,please let me know how can i configure this RAID without losing  or erase my first RAID

Comment: Create another volume, what kind of raid you are using and what adapter?

Comment: we are using RAID 1 and also i want to add two hardisk more in that also should configure in RAID 1

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the manufacturer of the servers/RAID controller. Some of them allow you to create another volume by using the convenient web interface, some of them will require some additional management software installed on OS (either Windows or Linux) and create a new RAID array using unique serial numbers or IDs of newly attached drives without erasing the previous one. 
You need to read RAID controller documentation to confirm possible operations.